# c++ logging - how to write a conditional macro for insertion operator that does nothing

Tags: c++, macros

I have a piece of code that uses [plog](https://github.com/SergiusTheBest/plog#colorconsoleappender) for logging, as below:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  static plog::ColorConsoleAppender<plog::TxtFormatter> consoleAppender;
  plog::init(plog::verbose, &consoleAppender);

  // Log severity levels are printed in different colors.
  LOG_VERBOSE << "This is a VERBOSE message";
  LOG_DEBUG << "This is a DEBUG message";
  LOG_INFO << "This is an INFO message";
  LOG_WARNING << "This is a WARNING message";
  LOG_ERROR << "This is an ERROR message";
  LOG_FATAL << "This is a FATAL message";

  return 0;

}
```

As this code is going to be part of a library, I don't want to emit any logs until / unless enabled by the application that is using it.  So, I am trying to see, if I can make the above logging code ineffective via some macro definitions.  I tried the following, but results in compilation errors:

```
#ifdef NO_LOGGING
#undef LOG_VERBOSE 
#define LOG_VERBOSE {}
#undef LOG_DEBUG 
#define LOG_DEBUG {}
#undef LOG_INFO 
#define LOG_INFO {}
#undef LOG_WARNING 
#define LOG_WARNING {}
#undef LOG_ERROR 
#define LOG_ERROR {}
#undef LOG_FATAL 
#define LOG_FATAL {}
#endif
```

This results in compilation error

```
log_test.cpp:25:15: error: expected expression   LOG_VERBOSE << "This is a VERBOSE message" ;
              ^ log_test.cpp:26:13: error: expected expression   LOG_DEBUG << "This is a DEBUG message";
            ^ log_test.cpp:27:12: error: expected expression   LOG_INFO << "This is an INFO message";
           ^ log_test.cpp:28:15: error: expected expression   LOG_WARNING << "This is a WARNING message";
              ^ log_test.cpp:29:13: error: expected expression   LOG_ERROR << "This is an ERROR message";
            ^ log_test.cpp:30:13: error: expected expression   LOG_FATAL << "This is a FATAL message";
            ^
```

Is there a way to get around this problem and have a proper disabling of the logs?

Comment: Why is everyone doing so much logging? Or at least, why are they writing loggers?

Comment: Why not wrap the code in a `#ifdef SOME_NAME` and then it will only be called if `SOME_NAME` is defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to do something like this:

```
struct black_hole_t
{
    template <typename T> black_hole_t operator<<(T &&)
    {
        return {};
    }
};

black_hole_t black_hole;

#define LOG_BLAH black_hole

// or #define LOG_BLAH black_hole_t{}
// But GCC generates 1 more instruction for it at -O0,
// which hurts my inner love for premature optimizations.
```

And hope that your compiler will optimize it to a no-op.

GCC 7.2 no-ops it with `-O1`, clang 4.0 requires at least `-O2`.

Comment: You don't even need the variable: `#define LOG_BLAH black_hole_t{}`.

Answer (score 2):

Here'a another possible solution.

```
#ifdef NO_LOGGING

struct EmptyLog {};

template <typename T>
EmptyLog& operator<<(EmptyLog& e, T)
{
   return e;
}

EmptyLog& NoLog()
{
   static EmptyLog e;
   return e;
}

#undef LOG_VERBOSE 
#define LOG_VERBOSE NoLog()
#undef LOG_DEBUG 
#define LOG_DEBUG NoLog()
#undef LOG_INFO 
#define LOG_INFO NoLog()
#undef LOG_WARNING 
#define LOG_WARNING NoLog()
#undef LOG_ERROR 
#define LOG_ERROR NoLog()
#undef LOG_FATAL 
#define LOG_FATAL NoLog()

#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  // Log severity levels are printed in different colors.
  LOG_VERBOSE << "This is a VERBOSE message";
  LOG_DEBUG << "This is a DEBUG message";
  LOG_INFO << "This is an INFO message";
  LOG_WARNING << "This is a WARNING message";
  LOG_ERROR << "This is an ERROR message";
  LOG_FATAL << "This is a FATAL message";

  return 0;
}
```

Note that it allows sequencing of messages. You can use:

```
  LOG_FATAL << "Unable to find login information for user\"" << user << "\".";
```