# Preprocessor, expand macro to nothing when undefined

Tags: c++, preprocessor

The preprocessor has always been black magic to me but I think I finally need to use it.

I have implemented a logger class which I want to conditionally (compile flag) expand to nothing if the flag is not set so that I don't get all my prints in production.

This would have a usecase like so

```
FO_LOG << name() << "Hello World"  << std::endl;
```

I thought I could define it like this

```
#ifdef TRACE
#define FO_LOG {return Faceoff::trace::log();}
#else
#define FO_LOG \
    if(false){\
        return Faceoff::trace::log();\
    }
#endif
```

But this won't compile with the following errors

```
no viable conversion from returned value of type 'Faceoff::trace' to function return type 'int'
                FO_LOG << name() << "omitted"  << std::endl;
                ^~~~~~
    /omitted/include/globals.h:69:16: note: expanded from macro 'FO_LOG'
            return Faceoff::trace::log();\
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now the error is clear, but I don't know how to express my intention in preprocessor syntax...

Comment: The preprocessor just replaces text. Does `{return Faceoff::trace::log();}  << name() << "Hello World"  << std::endl;` look like legitimate code to you?

Comment: Dupe of [c++ logging - how to write a conditional macro for insertion operator that does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762421/c-logging-how-to-write-a-conditional-macro-for-insertion-operator-that-does)

Comment: @KerrekSB No that should definitely not compile, but how do I define it so it is still a valid expression for the compiler? I thought I could trick it with the "if false" test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class devnull : public std::ostream {
    class devnullbuff : public std::streambuf {
    public:
        int overflow( int c ) { return c; }
    } m_nb;
public:
    devnull() : std::ostream( &m_nb ) {}
};
#ifdef TRACE
#define FO_LOG Faceoff::trace::log()
#else
#define FO_LOG devnull()
#endif
```

Assuming Faceoff::trace::log() returns some sort of ostream, then you can do what you want:

```
FO_LOG << name() << "Hello World"  << std::endl;
```

This is not quite efficient because it creates a new devnull object every time.  You can just create it once in your program and forward declare to it to avoid this.  It's not as elegant though.